# Information about Mercury hammer blow tenor sax

Tags: instruments, saxophone

I bought a very nice playing upper-level saxophone. It says "Mercury Design in USA". The seller told me the parts came from Korea and it was assembled in the USA.

Seller said:

> Double arms on all claps in the low registers, just like the Yanagisawa's.

Inscription:

> "Mercury musical design USA"

Serial nummer:

> JF0117H8.

It plays incredible, but I can't find any information about this peculiar sax. And the hammer blow is really rare. Have you seem hammer blow (does it translate like this: hamerslag) saxes before? Does anybody have any information about this sax?

[image: Mercury hammer blow tenor sax - on bench]

[image: Mercury hammer blow tenor sax - on stand]

[image: Mercury hammer blow tenor sax - closeup of elbow]

I've only found this strange website:
http://www.lk-js.com/en/info.asp?id=4

Comment: Checking in w/ my bro the sax repair/restore/performance guy... hope to have an answer soon.

Comment: Also got some info here http://forum.saxontheweb.net/showthread.php?207830-Coolest-sax-ever-Information-about-Mercury-hammer-blow-tenor-sax&p=2168798&posted=1#post2168798

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New and Asian. Basically if you have a few design ideas and a checkbook, you can get an Asian manufacturer to make their standard issue horn with your personal modifications and your brand name. And, yes, they make some good ones. Could be something like a music shop owner in Smalltown, USA who hoped to hit the big time.